# How can I perform an action on all occurrences of an element in a list?

Tags: python, list, nlp

I wanted to make texts readable for BERT-embeddings by inserting the [CLS] and [SEP] tokens. I tokenized my text so I have a list with every word and punctuation mark as element, however, I don't know how exactly I can add elements after every occurrence of '.' in my text.

Does anyone know what I can do? Or do you know if there is something that prepares BERT-readable-texts?

Comment: Along with the problem you should include the code you have up until this point (make some effort to answer your problem/question as SO is not a code writing service). After doing more research you can post what you've tried with a clear explanation of what isn't working and providing a minimal reproducible example. I suggest reading [How do I ask a Good Question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [Writing the Perfect Question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/). Also, be sure to [take the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).

Answer (score 0):

I think this answers your question:

https://github.com/google-research/bert#tokenization

As mentioned, you can see how they have done it in `run_classifier.py` and  `extract_features.py`.

However, you can also accomplish what you want by using regular expressions (regex). In python, this would look something like:

```
import re

regex = r"[.]"
test_str = "Hello . BERT . Goodbye ."
subst = ". [SEP]"

result = re.sub(regex, subst, test_str)

if result:
    print (result)
```